# How can I increment a date?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two dates as duedate as 03/03/2011 and returndate as 03/09/2011. I want to find the fine in double when I subtract duedate from returndate.How can duedate be incremented?

Comment: mydate.AddDays(1); to  increment the due date by one day...

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using some version of Visual Studio? If so, it seems like the context sensitive help would be a faster way to resolve your problems. It may not seem that way at first, but reading the help is a big part of a developer's improvement cycle and _learning how_ to read the help is a skill that must be practiced.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Following code might help you:

```
var dueDate = new DateTime(2011, 3, 3);

//if you want to increment six days
var dueDatePlus6Days = dueDate.AddDays(6);

//if you want to increment six months
var dueDatePlus6Months = dueDate.AddMonths(6);

var daysDiff1 = (dueDatePlus6Days - dueDate).TotalDays; //gives 6
var daysDiff2 = (dueDatePlus6Months - dueDate).TotalDays; //gives 184
```

Answer (score 3):

The logical solution would seem to be the AddDays method, as in the other answers.

However, I try (in general) never to use floating point (i.e. a double) when working with monetary or date values.

DateTime contains a time component and AddDays takes a double as argument (fractional part becomes time), so I tend to avoid use of that method.

Instead, I use

```
dueDatePlusOne = dueDate.AddTicks(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay);
```

This should result in slightly faster execution too. Not that it still matters much on today's hardware, but I started out coding for microprocessors with a <1 MHz clock speed and old PDP-8's and -11's and stuff like that back in the 1970's, and some habits never die ;)

Comment: Your AddTicks() also have one more advantage: 
It adds 24h, whereas AddDays() only adds ticks up to midnight, so you AddTicks() keeps the time intact, whereas AddDays() resets the time to 00:00:00

Comment: I just tried this because I had difficulty believing it, AddDays(1.0) adds 24 hours as well. Immediate window in a VB project in Visual studio: ? (#11/22/2016 01:02:03#).AddDays(1.0) -- result: #11/23/2016 01:02:03 AM#.  Same with Now.AddDays(1.0), the hour is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming returnDate, dueDate are DateTime objects:

```
double extraDays = (returnDate - dueDate).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 1):

May this can help you

```
DateTime dt_duedate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt_returndate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
System.TimeSpan diffResult = dt_returndate.Subtract(dt_duedate);
```